# Strange preprocessing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c-preprocessor

Something strange happens.

I have in my code in a local function

```
#ifdef abc
.
.
.
#endif
```

when I write on the top of the file

```
#define abc
```

it acts as if it isn't defined.  only when I define

```
#define abc
```

in the local function itself it reads the code in the ifdef.

This is strange because I thought that the compiler just goes over the whole file without details of functions to change the # preprocessing orders.  can't understand what's happening.  I am using visual-studio 2005.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably you had the #define before #include "stdafx.h". This is ignored.

Comment: LOL Is this a bug or a "feature" of visual studio?

Comment: @VJo:  It's a well-known caveat of using precompiled headers:  it's pretty much impossible to implement precompiled headers if it isn't guaranteed that the precompiled header is included before everything else (because the meaning of the included headers would be different in different translation units).  The fact that Visual C++ doesn't warn you when it ignores tokens that appear before the precompiled header inclusion is a "feature."

Answer (score 0):

I think you run the sample in release mode.so some block of code is not able to execute in release mode.what you made copy the line and paste somewhere so that it works.

The previous answer is not the right one.